# PDF generation php - Pass data each time or use template?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am making a pdf file with php. Currently using dompdf but open to suggestions. Data will also be retrieved from a database.++// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

**I am making a form in which i populate the fields with the username of the person logged in**

**Making PDF each time:**(just and example) Finding it hard to combine php variables with html code to make a whole document

```
$variable= Variable::findOrFail(session('id'));

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('$variable');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

**Or Shall i make a view which i turn into a pdf?**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Comment: View seems like the superior choice

Comment: @devk whats the best way to pass variables to the pdf?         $pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contract', $variable);

Comment: @user9820353 i pass vars like this: `$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfme', compact('input', 'cffEvents', 'cffEvents2'));` with compact.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your template does not include JS and its functions, DomPDF is a good choice in case you use template within view. However, (just an extra infor), if your template use JS, eg: draw a charge, element animation,..., you should you wkhtmltopdf.
2. The loadView method you are using is going to use the extract method before passing the data to the views. This method extracts all the array elements, and creates variables for them based on the key of the element. So, when you pass an array like `['a' => 'aVal']`, you can use `$a` variable in your template (which will return `aVal`). In your case, use `$data = ['variable' => $variable]` is a right way.

And, if you want to pass multi-variable: `$data = ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2, etc]`. Good luck!